# Re-feed some already crawled URL to spider/scheduler

Tags: python, scrapy

There is some URL (domain.com/list) which lists 10 links I need to crawl periodically. These links change pretty often each 30 seconds roughly, so I need to constantly re-crawl domain.com/list to check for new links. Crawling all this links sometimes takes more than 30 seconds because of size so I cannot cron a script to do it each 30 seconds since I could end up with several concurrent spiders. Missing some links because the spider takes too long during the first run is an acceptable situation though.

I wrote some spider middleware to remove already visited links (for cases in which the links change only partially). I tried to include in that process_spider_output a new Request for domain.com/list with dont_filter=True so the list is feeded again to the scheduler, but I end up with tons of those requests. My code is:

```
def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):

    for i in result:
        if isinstance(i, Request):
            state = spider.state.get('crawled_links', deque([]))
            if unquote(i.url) in state or i.url in state:
                print "removed %s" % i
                continue
        yield i

    yield spider.make_requests_from_url('http://domain.com/list')
```

This seems pretty ugly and I am not sure whether it works as intended. I also tried to hook spider idle and closed signals to try to re-crawl the site without success.

What's the best way to re-crawl specific urls to monitor changes that occur very often, and without closing the spider in use?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Crawling all this links sometimes takes more than 30 seconds because
>   of size so I cannot cron a script to do it each 30 seconds since I
>   could end up with several concurrent spiders.

There's a common practice of using a file containing a process PID as a mutual exclusion lock, and bailing out if the file exists, and the process is still running. If you put your spidering code into a program with this sort of structure...

```
import sys
import os

PIDFILE = '/tmp/mycrawler.pid'


def do_the_thing():
    # <your spider code here>


def main():

    # Check if we're already running
    if os.path.exists(PIDFILE):
        pid = int(open(PIDFILE, 'r').read())
        try:
            os.kill(pid, 0)
            print "We're already running as PID %d" % pid
            sys.exit(1)
        except OSError:
            pass

    # Write a PID file
    open(PIDFILE, 'w').write(str(os.getpid()))

    # Now do the thing, ensuring we delete PID file when done
    try:
        do_the_thing()
    finally:
        os.unlink(PIDFILE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...then you can run it from `cron` as often as you like, and it'll just wait until the last instance has finished before running again.